# How to add different colours to columns of the website

Tags: html, css, grid

I'm looking to add different colours to 2 columns of my website? I have css code which states the colour but I cant seem to get add two colours. Can someone help me out what I am doing wrong. Thank you

HTML Code:

```css
#myeducation1 {
    background: #FF8C00;/*yellow*/
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

#myeducation2 {
    background: #ec576b;/*pink*/
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<section id="education" name="education"></section>
    <div id="myeducation1">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you include the CSS you are using?

Comment: I've added the code above. I dont have much code skills so Im not even sure if im doing this correctly. appreciate the help

Comment: Is that the real code you're using? Because what you've posted will apply the code to both lots of text

Comment: yes it is. I tried adding another div but just overlaps it so I removed it. The code is what I have as it stands

Comment: See my comment and the others below for the solution and make sure to accept whichever answer is the most helpful as correct

Answer (score 0):

What kind of color form do you want? As I saw , there is only one #myeducation1 , no #myeducation2. If you want to paint different color on two columns in the same table you should modify on .col-xs-6 each one, not #myeducation1.  Btw .col-xs-6 css is for all of element which have this css.  Seperate them by add another class for each

Answer (score 0):

Your css refers to two different ids and only one is used. A simple way to achieve what you want is to apply these ids to the correct elements.

The amended code would look like this (notice how your original classes `#myeducation1` and `#myeducation2` have been applied *directly* to the column divs)

HTML:

```
<section id="education" name="education"></section>
<div id="topDiv"> <!-- this class replaces the one you had here, keeping padding  only -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="myeducation1" class="col-xs-6">
        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="myeducation2" class="col-xs-6">
        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#topDiv { /* this replaces the old reference you had at #myeducation1*/
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px
}

#myeducation1 {
  background: #FF8C00;
}

#myeducation2 {
  background: #ec576b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is happened just because you didn't used the `#myeducation2` on your html code.I'm added a snippet with just adding that id too.

```css
#myeducation1 {
 background: #FF8C00;/*yellow*/
 padding-top: 30px;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
}

#myeducation2 {
 background: #ec576b;/*pink*/
 padding-top: 30px;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<section id="education" name="education"></section>
 <div >
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    
    <div class="col-xs-6" id="myeducation1">
     
     <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.
                                        </p>
    
    </div>
                                
                                    <div class="col-xs-6" id="myeducation2">
     <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.
                                        </p>
    
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've just forgotten to add the other div. Add an ID of `myeducation1` to one div, and `myeducation2` to the other and it should work